# Are all RegExp solvable in O(n)?

Tags: complexity-classes, regular-expressions

I'm wondering if all features, that are often part of modern RegEx engines, are solvable in O(n). I'm talking about features like repeating patterns `([abc]+);\1` would match `abc;abc` but not `abc;cba`, lazy or not greedy repetition operators `[ab]+?ba$` would match `abba` or `aaaabbbbba` but not `ababa`.

I know that things like anchors (`^` and `$`), optional operator (`a?`), character classes (`[abc]`, or `[^abc]`) and the plus operator can be reduced to nominal regex operations or are simple checks in the end.

Comment: https://perl.plover.com/NPC/ , https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00176043/

Comment: do you have a reference that defines the extended RegExp? Can't figure it out from your post.

Comment: @AmeerJ the combination of Emil's comment and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356328/1950267 already answers my question pretty much. I've found the stackoverflow link while looking for a specification of extended RegExp...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@emil's comment](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47058/are-all-regexp-solvable-in-on#comment104496_47058) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356328/1950267) stackoverflow answer, I now know that [POSIX extended regular expressions](https://regular-expressions.mobi/posix.html?wlr=1) are solvable in O(n) but backreferences are at least NP-hard and maybe NP-complete.